Is $\ln(ax^2+y^2)\in L^2_{\operatorname{loc}}(\mathbb{R}^2)$?
Let $a>0$ and define
$$f(x,y)=\ln(ax^2+y^2)$$
for each $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\backslash\{(0,0)\}$. Is $f$ in $L^2_{\operatorname{loc}}(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathcal{L}^2)$, where $\mathcal{L}^2$ is the two-dimensional Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Is $f$ integrable for all compact of your set ?

Is $f$ defined on all compact of $\Bbb{R}^2$?  (You probably want to ask whether $f$ in $L^2(\Bbb{R}^2 \smallsetminus {(0,0)}, \mathcal{L}^2)$...)
